# Bessel function with shifted argument

Tags: functions, special-functions

Is there any standard practice which may represents $J_m(a\pm kx)$ in terms of $J_m(kx)$

Comment: Please ask your question at [math.se]. This is a site for the _Mathematica_ software.

Answer (score 0):

In wikipedia it states (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function). 
\begin{align}
  I_\nu(z_1+z_2)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}I_{\nu-k}(z_1)I_k(z_2)
\end{align}
However I am not sure where this is referenced from.